# Working in background

Tags: android, service, background, skype, foreground

Actually, I found lots of answers for my questions but this time I am totally stuck.

My question is very easy. I am building a radio streaming application for .pls streams and when the user press the home button, I want my application to continue working. I think lots of you know ebuddy and Skype or the basic media players. They are putting themselves to notification bar and you can easily reach them from this place. I tried to create a notification for my app, but when I click the icon on the notification bar, I can't reach my app. It directly opens a new version of my app and I can't control the streaming, the initial working app is no longer existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to read the descriptions for LaunchMode: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

You want to launch your Activity as singleInstance

Edit: maybe singleTask would be better.

This is the workflow you want to achieve:
[image: workflow]

All background work has to be done by a service. Implementing one is quite simple, almost as creating an activity.

There are many examples on how to do it:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
- http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html
- http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/AndroidService

Comment: Yes, at the beginning this was looking like the solution but when I add this, my app should be closed (never started) for taking URL to app. This is the only way. If I open it first and then I try to open a .pls file, app doesn't do anything. Because of this, I think I have to understand the services or I have to disable HOME button and force users to use EXIT, but I don't want this.

Comment: @Ada this is not to avoid a service. I assumed your music was already streamed by a service, and you wanted to show up the app to control the stream. All background work has to be done by a service. Implementing one is quite simple, almost as creating an activity. There is an example on how to do it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html . Another example here: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

Comment: Actually, I was calling my media streaming player as a thread, but I understand it is totally wrong way. If I understand the situation right, I have to modify my streaming player class as a service. Am I right?

Comment: @Ada Pretty much yes. You keep an activity for the UI and the service to replace the second thread. Check the documentation for the IBinder class, which is an easy way to communicate between the service and the activity. Take your time, and go through the links I posted. You can then ask new questions here with implementation details if needed. If you already have the streaming class implemented as a thread, then you won;t have much difficulty creating the service. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need the actual music playing part - or the part that should continue running in the background -  to be a service, and the gui to be an activity. The notification you made should bring your activity gui to the front with a flag_activity_reorder_to_front.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer for my problem but I don't know how to use services and actually I tried something about them but I didn't achieve anything about my app. I will try to understand connection between service and app.